# How to propery finish a PHP page after an exception is thrown and caught?

Tags: php, exception

I am working on my first major PHP/MySQL application. I use the Exception handling mechanism to handle possible DB errors. On some pages, I use several queries to obtain the relevant data from the database. The part of the page issuesn those queries is within one try-catch block and I write a customized error message in the catch block.
My problem: the queries are within different  blocks on my page, and when a DB exception is thrown, processing immediately goes to the catch block and makes it not really possible to render the page in valid XHTML because in the catch block it is not known which XHTML tags should be closed. 
I was thinking about redirecting to a custom error page showing the error mesage but this appears to be discouraged by some people. I think this should be a pretty trivial issue but wonder what is the recommended practice.
Hope for some hints!

Comment: All of my PHP is done in answer to AJAX calls. The PHP returns a JSON string of an object. The object contains `errorStatus`, `message` and `data` attributes. I set the `errorStatus` and put some descriptive text in `message`.

Comment: If the db errors are a rare event, I don't think anyone'll worry about valid xhtml being emitted by the script. "Your credit card has been charged 5 times by mistake" would not result in "zomg, forget the CC stuff... I see invalid xhtml! SUE SUE SUE!"

Comment: Surely nobody will sue me for invalid XHMTL.. but I am a purist :)
I thought about an alternative solution: buffering all content between the outer #content div tag and print this to the output after the last query. When an excecption is thrown, I write the error message instead of this buffered content.
Has anyone heared of this workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Change the default error handler. Log them in a database

2) use output buffering

3) last line of your Catch{} block, have it do a header("location: error.html") redirect to a generic error handler.

Comment: 2) was what I was thinking about, see my previous comment. 3) uses redirection and I wondered whether this is the best practice...

Answer (score 1):

You should use ob_start() to start buffering the output, and then you have finished to render all the HTML, use ob_flush() to send the HTML code back to the user.
If an error occured, you can generate a special page by calling ob_clean() to clean the buffer and then display your error page.

Exemple :

```
ob_start();

echo "My title";

try{
   $myDB = Database::getInstance();
   $userName = $myDB->query("SELECT name FROM user"); // send an exception
   echo "Welcome ".$userName;
} catch (Exception $e) {
   ob_clean();
   echo "Error, please try again";
}

ob_flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm shure that DB query error is mostly debug enviroment issue or code error. I also prefer to validate and escape values in DB query before running it and show validation result, when it failed.

So, if DB exception even appeared, i log it (using simple error_log, including full request data, get, post, url, referrer) and show 500 error page without any redirect. I think, that redirect is a bad practice - you can't refresh page and repeat error, visitors and QA can't send you invalid page link.

Answer (score 0):

I used the ob_Start(), ob_flush() and ob_clean() method and it does what I excepted so I keep using this. 
I will wonder whether this is considered as good practice, IMHO generating invalid XHTML should always be avoided.
Of course an error in the query is a bug and one can argue whether this should be handled in the production code. But my guess is that in the future a lot of maintenance will be done and errors will be inevitable. And they should be presented as nice as possible and surely not in the form of a white blank screen...